# Create objects with logic using passed in arguments in function

Tags: javascript

I have this function where I create an object `const dataObj` to be used in the function, with the   `labels` and `valuesX` passed in.

```
function drawChart(labels, values0, values1, values2, ...many more objects) {
    const dataObj = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [
            {
                fill: false,
                label: "temp0",
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                borderColor: 'red',
                data: values0
            },
            {
                fill: false,
                label: "temp1",
                backgroundColor: 'purple',
                borderColor: 'purple',
                data: values1
            },
            {
                fill: false,
                label: "temp2",
                backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                borderColor: 'yellow',
                data: values2
            },
            ...many more objects
        }
    }
    ...not meaningful code
}
```

Is there a way to  create  the `dataObj` with logic inside the function instead of creating all the objects literally one by one with a `for` loop or similar?
My problem comes when I need to refer to the respective arguments `valueX` in the logic to create the objets with logic.

My approach is to create a functions that generate the objects, but my problem comes when I need to refer to the argument with logic. Check the comment `//PROBLEM HERE`

```
function getDatasetArray(values0, values1, values2, values3, values4,
    values5, values6, values7, values8, values9, 
    values10, values11) {
    const datasets = [];
    const colors = [];
    const lables = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        const obj = {
            fill: false,
            label: lables[i],
            backgroundColor: colors[i],
            borderColor: colors[i],
            data: values0 // PROBLEM HERE
        }
        datasets.push(obj);
    }

    return datasets;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

take in your values as an array.

```js
function drawChart(labels, values) { // take values as array
    const dataObj = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: []
    }
    let colors = ["red", "purple", ...], i = 0;
    values.forEach(value => {
        let obj = {
                fill: false,
                label: "temp" + i,
                backgroundColor: color[i],
                borderColor: color[i],
                data: values[i]
        } 
        dataObj.datasets.push(obj);
        i++;
    });
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `values` as an array as arguements cannot be consumed with indices.

#### Solution

```js
function drawChart(values) {
  // rest of code

  for(let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    const obj = {
      // ..
      data: values[i] // access i-th value here
    }

    datasets.push(obj);
  }

  // rest of code
}
```

#### Note

It's a **bad practice** to pass so many arguments to your function as it would result in **poor code quality** which is **difficult to maintain**. Moreover, the type of data each argument represents is same, i.e. `value` so it must be **grouped** in an object or here, array.

Answer (score 1):

you can update your `getDatasetArray` as

```
const getDatasetArray = (...values) => { // take values using es6-spread
  const datasets = [];
  const colors = [];
  const lables = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { // iterate for values
    const obj = {
      fill: false,
      label: lables[i],
      backgroundColor: colors[i],
      borderColor: colors[i],
      data: values[i]  // put value into data-key
    }
    datasets.push(obj);
  }
  return datasets;
}
```

and `drawChart` as

```
function drawChart(labels, ...values) { //use spread here too
  // rest of your code
}
```